# ASP.Net populate checkboxes quick solution?

Tags: asp.net, checkbox

I'm just wondering if there is a quick way to to populate my checkboxes from my query

Currently I do this

```
If Trim(DataTable.Rows(0).Item("COLUMN1").ToString()) = "Y" Then
cb1.Checked = True
Else
cb1.Checked = False
End If

If Trim(DataTable.Rows(0).Item("COLUMN2_FLAG").ToString()) = "Y" Then
cb2.Checked = True
Else
cb2.Checked = False
End If

If Trim(DataTable.Rows(0).Item("COLUMN3_FLAG").ToString()) = "Y" Then
cb3.Checked = True
Else
cb3.Checked = False
End If
```

Altogether I have 15 checkboxes and it seems like a lot of un-neccessary code to just populate my checkboxes

any ideas of a quick way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your if statements require a boolean to evaluate their flow.  The checkboxes also recieve a boolean value.

I think you could just do:

```
cb1.Checked = Trim(DataTable.Rows(0).Item("COLUMN1").ToString()) == "Y"
cb2.Checked = Trim(DataTable.Rows(0).Item("COLUMN2_FLAG").ToString()) == "Y"
cb3.Checked = Trim(DataTable.Rows(0).Item("COLUMN3_FLAG").ToString()) == "Y"
```

I work with C# not vb so sorry if syntax isnt correct.  But basically if the boolean expression evaluates to true it will set checked  = true and if it evaluates false it will set it to false.

Comment: Your welcome.  To write back into your database or datatable you should be able to do something like this string YorN = CheckBox1.Checked ? "Y" : "N";  thats c# code but maybe you can translate to VB

Answer (score 1):

If your naming conventions are too be trusted and will remain consistent you can use a loop to work your way through an array of your checkboxes. Sorry this is in C#  but I am not confident in my VB.NET syntax. Hopefully it should be easy to convert.

```
Checkbox[] checkboxes = new Checkbox[] { cb1, cb2, cb3.....};
foreach(var checkbox in checkboxes)
{
    string index = checkbox.Id.Substring(2);
    if (DataTable.Rows(0).Item("COLUMN" + index) != null)
          checkbox.Checked = DataTable.Rows(0).Item("COLUMN" + index).ToString() == "Y";
    else if (DataTable.Rows(0).Item("COLUMN" + index + "_FLAG" ) != null)
          checkbox.Checked = DataTable.Rows(0).Item("COLUMN" + index + "_FLAG").ToString() == "Y";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in a function taking a string and a checkbox as a parameter.

```
public function func(byval col as string) as boolean

  return Trim(DataTable.Rows(0).Item(col).ToString()) = "Y" Then

end sub
```

Now you can just call that function and assign to each checkbox.

Comment: Why not just return (DataTable.Rows(0).Item(col).ToString()) = "Y" ?

Answer (score 0):

If its possible, you might consider building your checkboxes using the data and a Repeater control?